# Calculate the integral $\int_{\gamma} \frac{dz}{z - 1 - i} $ where the path is the line joining the point $z_1$ and $z_2$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

> Calculate the integral
>
> $$\int_{\gamma} \frac{dz}{z - 1 - i}$$
>
> For a path given by the line joining $z_1 = 2i$ and $z_2 = 3$.

Initially I parameterized the path as the line $$y = -\frac{2x}{3} + 2$$ and then I used the complexification of this curve:

$$\gamma = t - 2i\left(\frac{t}{3} - 1\right)$$

applied in the integral, considering:

$$z = t - 2i\left(\frac{t}{3} - 1\right)
\quad\implies\quad
dz = dt -2i\left(\frac{dt}{3} - 0\right) = dt\left(1 - \frac{2i}{3}\right)$$

which gives me:

$$
\int_{0}^{3} \frac{(1 - \frac{2i}{3}) \, dt}{(1 - \frac{2i}{3})t +2i - 1 + i}
= (3 - 2i)\int_{0}^{3} \frac{dt}{(3 - 2i)t +3(3i - 1)}.
$$

To solve this integral I used the substitution:

$$
w = (3 - 2i)t + 3(3i -1)
\quad\implies\quad
\frac{dw}{(3 - 2i)} = dt$$

which leads me to:

$$(3 - 2i) \int_{9i - 3}^{3i + 8} \frac{dw}{(3 - 2i)}\, \frac{1}{w}
= \frac{(3 - 2i)}{(3 - 2i)} \int_{9i - 3}^{3i + 8} \frac{dw}{w}
= \ln \left(\frac{3i + 8}{9i - 3}\right)$$

I would like to know if my approach is correct, and if it's not, what should I do differently!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function that you are integrating has a primitive, which is $\ln(z-1-i)$, where $\ln$ is the main logarithm. So,\begin{align}\int_\gamma\frac{\mathrm dz}{z-1-i}&=\ln(-1+i)-\ln(2-i)\\&=\ln|-1+i|+\frac{3\pi}4i-\left(\ln|2-i|-\arctan\left(\frac12\right)i\right)\\&=\frac12\ln\left(\frac25\right)+\left(\frac{3\pi}4+\arctan\left(\frac12\right)\right)i.\end{align}

In your answer, you don't say what $\ln$ is.